# passing array from .js file to .html file

Tags: android, charts, titanium, pie-chart

i am creating a pie chart for android devices using some additional plugin in Titanium Studio so, this is my app.js

```
var earn=[' ',' '];
var textfield1 = Ti.UI.createTextField({
    value:earn[0],
    keyboardType: Titanium.UI.KEYBOARD_NUMBER_PAD, 
});
win.add(textfield1);
var textfield2 = Ti.UI.createTextField({
    value:earn[1],
    keyboardType: Titanium.UI.KEYBOARD_NUMBER_PAD, 
});
win.add(textfield2);
var webview = Titanium.UI.createWebView({
 url: 'chart.htm'
});
win.add(webview);
```

and this is my chart.htm

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="wz_jsgraphics.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="pie.js"></script>

<div id="pieCanvas" style="overflow: auto; position:relative;height:350px;width:380px;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var p = new pie();
p.add("Jan",100);
p.add("Feb",200);
p.render("pieCanvas", "Pie Graph")

</script>
```

If i were to use array "earn[0]" for my "Jan" how do i call the array from the app.js file? When i change value "100" to "earn[0]", the pie chart will not show. Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `earn` array will not dynamically update when you change the textfields, if that is what you are asking. You have to listen for when the texfields fire change events, capture that event, and get the new values, now you can update the pie chart.

To make it so that up update the graph whenever someone changes the value in the texfields you need to do this:

```
/* app.js */
var textfield1 = Ti.UI.createTextField({
    value:' ',
    keyboardType: Titanium.UI.KEYBOARD_NUMBER_PAD, 
});
/* This is the important part */
textfield1.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    var earn = [textfield1.value, textfield2.value];
    webview.evalJS('createPie(' + JSON.stringify(earn) +');');
});

var textfield2 = Ti.UI.createTextField({
    value:' ',
    keyboardType: Titanium.UI.KEYBOARD_NUMBER_PAD, 
});
/* This is the important part */
textfield2.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    var earn = [textfield1.value, textfield2.value];
    // DO this
    webview.evalJS('createPie(' + JSON.stringify(earn) +');');
});

var webview = Titanium.UI.createWebView({
 url: 'chart.htm'
});

// Add views
win.add(textfield1);
win.add(textfield2);
win.add(webview);
```

And in your HTML (I've taken from Mohit's well crafted HTML):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="wz_jsgraphics.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="pie.js"></script>

<div id="pieCanvas" style="overflow: auto; position:relative;height:350px;width:380px;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function createPie(arr) {
    var earn = eval(arr); // convert from JSON string to JS, alternatively use JSON.parse
    var p = new pie();
    p.add("Jan", earn[0]);
    p.add("Feb", earn[1]);
    p.render("pieCanvas", "Pie Graph");
}
</script>
```

Now you have the bones, you may have to mess with the createPie() function, check out the link Mohit sent, this is written out in detail there.

Comment: ok, i got the solution, thanks to josiah, thank you for helping :)

Comment: eval(arr) is not a good method(its vulnerable to attacks), instead use JSON.parse(arr).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

App.js

```
var earn = [100, 200];

var textfield1 = Ti.UI.createTextField({
    value: earn[0],
    keyboardType: Titanium.UI.KEYBOARD_NUMBER_PAD,
});
win.add(textfield1);

var textfield2 = Ti.UI.createTextField({
    value: earn[1],
    keyboardType: Titanium.UI.KEYBOARD_NUMBER_PAD,
});
win.add(textfield2);

var webview = Titanium.UI.createWebView({
    url: 'chart.htm'
});
win.add(webview);

webView.addEventListener('load', function (e) {
    webview.evalJS('createPie(earn);');
});
```

Chart.htm

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="wz_jsgraphics.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="pie.js"></script>

<div id="pieCanvas" style="overflow: auto; position:relative;height:350px;width:380px;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function createPie(arr) {
    var p = new pie();
    p.add("Jan", arr[0]);
    p.add("Feb", arr[1]);
    p.render("pieCanvas", "Pie Graph");
}
</script>
```

Checkout this link for more help :  http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/73121/passing-variable-from-titanium-js-class-to-html-script-

Comment: yes i understand that, but if i want to assign the input text (textfield1 & textfield2) into the array? if i declare at the array, it will be fixed.

Comment: Because you shouldn't be declaring it with an array, you have to fetch the updated values.

Comment: meaning i dont use earn[0] and change to textfield1.value?